# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to gradle build the project after adding the a new dependency in `build.gradle(Module.app)` but getting the following error . Not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Dependency trying to add : com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

this is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.londonappbrewery.climapm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    complie 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

Comment: spelling mistake its `compile` not complie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `compile`. Not `complie`. There's a typo.

Actually, it's a method call. In Groovy, we can [leave the parenthesis for top-level expressions](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses). And that's why you are getting an error like:

> Could not find method complie()

Comment: Thanks Dinesh . its working well . couldn't see the typo .